# mongodb How to make age field in sum not count

Tags: mongodb

If you see, age field and using sum operator in mongodb is the same as normal SQL count operator.
Can you please explain how to use correct sum in mongodb

```
> db.test.find()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("544654d01cdcaf6a66c188e8"),
        "age" : 23,
        "name" : "Alex"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("544654f01cdcaf6a66c188ec"),
        "age" : 33,
        "name" : "Alex"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("544654fb406947798c239544"),
        "age" : 14,
        "name" : "Alex"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5446550a406947798c239547"),
        "age" : 25,
        "name" : "Oleg"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("54465523406947798c23954a"),
        "age" : 15,
        "name" : "Oleg"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("54465538406947798c23954e"),
        "age" : 10,
        "name" : "Mark"
}


> db.test.aggregate([{$group:{_id:"$name","age":{$sum:1}}}])
{ "_id" : "Mark", "age" : **1** }
{ "_id" : "Oleg", "age" : **2** }
{ "_id" : "Alex", "age" : **3** }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write as

```
db.test.aggregate([{$group:{_id:"$name","age":{$sum:"$age"}}}])
```

to sum as you expected.

The operand of **$sum** is an expression, **sum** is made according to the final result of this expression, added to filed **age** for this group.